# Programmatically add port forwarding entry into router using upnp?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, networking, portforwarding, upnp

Does someone have a simple example on how to add a port forwarding entry with upnp into the router using c++?

Comment: Here's a C# library which does it. http://github.com/theanti9/SharpUPnP

Comment: I am not an expert on c++ so porting that would be impossible for me, but I will take a look to see how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [some code that does this here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/41701acc-22d5-42d1-87e1-7f4dd5f1b666).  Although the title references Visual Basic, the included code is in C++.